# NFS service not enabled

Tags: centos, nfs

I installed the `nfs-ganesha` (package version `nfs-ganesha-2.6.3-1.el7.x86_64`), but when I tried to enable NFS service. I am getting this error:

```
root@gpfs01 ~]# mmces service enable nfs

gpfs01:  : unknown locale
gpfs01:  The NFS service can not be enabled because it is not installed.
gpfs01:  The file /etc/ganesha/gpfs.ganesha.nfsd.conf was not found.
gpfs01:  mmcesop: Command failed. Examine previous error messages to determine cause.
gpfs01:  : unknown locale
mmces service: Command failed. Examine previous error messages to determine cause.
```

After installed the `nfs-ganesha` getting this status :

```
[root@gpfs01 ~]# systemctl status nfs-ganesha

● nfs-ganesha.service - NFS-Ganesha file server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-ganesha.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-02-20 12:34:48 IST; 3s ago
     Docs: http://github.com/nfs-ganesha/nfs-ganesha/wiki
  Process: 28844 ExecStop=/bin/dbus-send --system --dest=org.ganesha.nfsd --type=method_call /org/ganesha/nfsd/admin org.ganesha.nfsd.admin.shutdown (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 30236 ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c /usr/bin/sleep 2 && /bin/dbus-send --system   --dest=org.ganesha.nfsd --type=method_call /org/ganesha/nfsd/admin  org.ganesha.nfsd.admin.init_fds_limit (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 30224 ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c prlimit --pid $MAINPID --nofile=$NOFILE:$NOFILE (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 30222 ExecStart=/bin/bash -c ${NUMACTL} ${NUMAOPTS} /usr/bin/ganesha.nfsd ${OPTIONS} ${EPOCH} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 30223 (ganesha.nfsd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nfs-ganesha.service
           └─30223 /usr/bin/ganesha.nfsd -L /var/log/ganesha/ganesha.log -f /etc/ganesha/ganesha.co...

Feb 20 12:34:46 gpfs01 systemd[1]: Starting NFS-Ganesha file server...
Feb 20 12:34:48 gpfs01 systemd[1]: Started NFS-Ganesha file server.
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? You talk about two different services `nfs` vs. `nfs-ganesha`.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/568218/cannot-get-nfs-ganesha-to-work-on-gpfs-cluster

Comment: I haven't  used GPFS, but there's a wiki page here that may help: https://github.com/nfs-ganesha/nfs-ganesha/wiki/GPFS